# shell script wget to gives download links error

Tags: shell, curl, wget

I am looking for a shell script that can:

1. Read download links from a text file using either wget or curl
2. Fetch/download the links line by line
3. Create log file either for error message of any link that are failed to download or successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below command.

```
cat list.txt | xargs wget -o logfile
```

Where 
**"list.txt"** contains the list of the files to be downloaded like below.

```
www.google.com
www.yahoo.com
www.facebook.com
```

The log's will be stored in the file **"logfile"** which is specified after the **-o** option.